# behaviour of autoreconf on source packages

Tags: autotools, autoconf

I got a project that has, say 10 directories (as a tarball). I edited the top level Makefile.am so as to exclude from the build, say 5 of the directories. Then I ran autoreconf

(Is this really a legal step? After all, I do not have an svn repository. I just got a source tarball).

I could now configure and build. Wishing to distribute this skimmed version, I created another tarball with `make dist` . On the client machine, when I try to configure (without running autoreconf), I get error:

```
error: cannot find input file: <excluded directory>/Makefile.in
```

I do not understand the client machine knows the existence of `<excluded directory>`. If I run autoreconf before creating the distribution with skimmed Makefile.am, won't the top level Makefile.in be updated so as to reflect these changes?

Thank you,

Elan.

PS: For the skimmed package, `make distcheck` of the modified source failed, with error 'Tcl configuration files not found' (The project has some Tcl/Tk). But `make dist` created a tar ball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to look for a call to `AC_CONFIG_FILES([ ... ])` (where ... is a list of files) in `configure.ac`, and remove `<excluded directory>/Makefile` from that list. If you don't, then `configure` will look for `Makefile.in` in `<excluded directory>` and try to transform it into `Makefile`, as you have found out.